# GNU make .env:6: *** unterminated variable reference. Stop

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-make, gnu

I have windows 10 and installed GNU Make 4.3 Built for Windows32. This is my first time using GNU make and it gave me an error like this

```
.env:6: *** unterminated variable reference. Stop.
```

my .env file contain

```
POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
POSTGRES_PASS="<MY_DB_PASS>"
POSTGRES_DB="<MY_DB>"
PG_HOST="localhost"
PG_PORT="5432"
SECRET_KEY="<MY_SECRET_KEY>"
DEBUG=True
ALLOWED_HOSTS="localhost 127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think that you're saving yourself by adding quotes.  And, if this variable is parsed by a shell then you are.

But, make doesn't use quotes.  The value of a variable is the complete contents to the right of the equal sign (after any initial whitespace is skipped).  So for example:

```
POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
```

If parsed by the shell, the value of the `POSTGRES_USER` variable is `postgres` because the shell interprets the quotes.  But make doesn't interpret quotes so the above line results in `POSTGRES_USER` make variable having the value `"postgres"` (including the quotes).

Now for your issue.  Line 6 of your file is:

```
SECRET_KEY="<MY_SECRET_KEY>"
```

and you don't show us the text of your secret key.

First, this is wrong even in shell syntax: you must use single-quotes here not double quotes, and even that will not be right if your secret key contains single quotes itself; you'd have to escape that.

However that error means that in your secret key you have the character sequence `$(` or `${` which make interprets as starting a variable reference: since there is no close paren or brace you get this error.

The short answer is, there's no portable way to use the same file sourced by both make and the shell if the values of the variable assignments contain any sort of special character (including whitespace).

Usually people do something like base64 encode their secret keys, so that those special characters are not a problem.